# Is there a way to hide overriden credentials settings from Scrapy output?

Tags: python, scrapy

When overriding default settings values like `FTP_PASSWORD` or `MAIL_PASS` they're automatically displayed on console output.

```
2020-10-01 14:20:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: foo)
2020-10-01 14:20:45 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.7.6
2020-10-01 14:20:45 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-10-01 14:20:45 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'foo',
 'MAIL_FROM': 'foo@bar.com',
 'MAIL_HOST': 'smtp.foo',
 'MAIL_PASS': 'baz',
 'MAIL_PORT': 587,
 'MAIL_USER': 'foo',
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 '
               'Firefox/64.0'}
2020-10-01 14:20:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 1ca2431dbad58eed
...
```

One solution could be to simply disable log with `LOG_ENABLED=False` but I'm looking for a way to remove it or hide the value as the log might be shared with third parties.

Comment: Have you considered post-processing the logs? I don’t think Scrapy supports this at the moment.

Comment: @Gallaecio Not yet, I was looking for a solution on Scrapy side first. Is this something that could be supported by Scrapy ? We could simply filter the dict before displaying it in [scrapy.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/004b40a7193a7c0c5138abe764cad6d1d9a4fc57/scrapy/crawler.py#L59).

Comment: You could open a feature request for this. But I personally do not see much value in it. Hiding secrets in logs feels a bit out of the scope of Scrapy to me.

Comment: I understand your point but it's not really hiding secrets in logs (which is I assume is out of the scope), it's more not displaying secrets in logs (which I think is totally related to Scrapy). It's seems a bit overkill to me to post-process the logs compared to not display secrets.

Comment: I assume that those secrets should also be hidden in other parts of the logs. Some DEBUG messages may mention them as well.

Comment: I didn't see secrets in other parts of the logs so far, but you're absolutely right, they might be displayed elsewhere even if I don't get the purpose.